# Need to find a way to call the locator which does the same in two different places inside web page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, indexing

There are two panels in my web page,
There is a drop down which is located in each of the Panel,
Here the scenario is it will fill the details on the first panel and then will go to second panel, since I am using same method/logic to click the dropdown,while filling in the second panel - it checks for xpath in first panels as there is a change(index change) in the xpath.

I am residing in a method and calling the locator but there is no option to concatenate(with a int) a locator unlike string - Instead of using a seperate method with calling seperate xpaths, is there any way we can achieve this tricky part..

I know Understanding here is quite a challenge ‍♂️‍♂️, but any thought is always welcome..

Expecting a Resolution

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML and your code attempts.